# how to hide table using wicket

Tags: wicket

I want to hide table based on conditions.I got error using this code.please help me to come out this error.

//IN Wicket :

```
<table class="jtrac jtrac-view" width="100%" wicket:id="request">
        <tr>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<table class="jtrac jtrac-view" width="100%" wicket:id="response">
        <tr >
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
        </tr>
</table>

I wrote java code like this.

WebMarkupContainer request = new WebMarkupContainer("request");
WebMarkupContainer response= new WebMarkupContainer("response");
add(request );
add(response);

if(time == null || time.equals("")) {           
response.setVisible(false);
add(response);          
}else {         
request.setVisible(false);
add(request);
}
```

Comment: You add your componets two times based on condition that probably gives you an exception that the child is already rendered.

Answer (score 2):

```
   add(request());
   add(response());

   private WebMarkupContainer request() {
      WebMarkupContainer r = new WebMarkupContainer("request") {

         @Override
         protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(StringUtils.isEmpty(time))
         }

      };
      r.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
      return r;
   }

   private WebMarkupContainer response() {
      WebMarkupContainer r = new WebMarkupContainer("response") {

         @Override
         protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(time));
         }

      };
      r.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
      return r;
   }
```

`StringUtils` is from Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html